# Python Program Freezes computer

Tags: python

I have been programming in python for a little while now, and decided to teach my friend as well. I asked him to make a method that would return a list of all the factors of a number, he gave me a script that was a little inefficient but still looked like it should have worked to me. However when run the program freezes up both my and his computer (I have a top of the line gaming pc so I don't think it is using to many resources). I showed him how to fix it, however I still cannot pinpoint what is causing the problem. Here is the code, thanks for your time!

```
def factors(numb):
    facs = []
    for i in range(1,int(numb // 2)):
        if numb % i == 0:
            facs.append(i)
    for i in facs:
        facs.append((numb / i))
    return facs.sort()
```

p.s. it never throws an error, even after having been let run for a while. Also it is in python 3.4

Comment: What value does `numb` have when this happens?

Comment: note that this will always return `None`, since `facs.sort` is an in-place function that returns `None`. Maybe `sorted(facs)`? But regardless we'd need to know how the function is called.

Comment: Sorry, whatever number I put into it causes the problem. I am calling it in a print statement i.e. print(factors(120)) i have tried using big and small numbers

Comment: You can simply `return [i for i in range(1,int(numb // 2)) if not i % 2]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this fragment:

```
for i in facs:
        facs.append((numb / i))
```

You have a self-incrementing sequence here.

Comment: You could fix this by doing `for i in facs[:]`

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is here:

```
for i in facs:
    facs.append((numb / i))
```

The for loop is iterating over every number in facs, and each time it does it adds a new number to the end. So each time it gets one place closer to the end of the list, the list gets one place longer. This makes an infinite loop and slowly swallows up all your memory.

EDIT: Solving the problem

The loop isn't actually necessary (and neither is the sorting, as the function produces an already sorted list)

```
def factors(numb):
    facs = []
    for i in range(1,int(numb // 2)):
        if numb % i == 0:
        facs.append(i)
return facs
```

Should work fine.

Comment: i had a similar problem like this where it was an infinite loop in python idle script mode and after i excecuted it everything froze.like no response from python nothing from windows task mangaer shortcut and after sometime i closed the lap and now when i on it theres is no display..the entire laptop got crashed just by a 7 lines of python code

Answer (score 1):

Try to analyse these lines(7,8), Here logic in not looking correct as you aspect(infinite loop).

```
for i in facs:
        facs.append((numb / i))
```

otherwise test it.

```
def factors(numb):
    l = [1,2,3,4]
    for i in l:
        print i
        l.append(numb/i)

factors(10) // function call
```